# How to handle interrupted In App Purchase Downloads?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have some In App Purchases that download Apple Hosted Content when purchased. They are downloading just fine so far.

But I'm having trouble finding good documentation on how to handle what to do if the downloads are interrupted, say if the user quits the app.

So far if I exit the app and return to it, I am asked to login to my sandbox ID, I think because you cannot finish a download transaction until the content has been downloaded, so the transaction is still active.

Does anyone know how to handle this or know of something online that can me pointed in the right direction? Thanks.